# EF6 - Cannot resolve symbol 'MapLeftKey'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to map a many-to-many relationship and EVERY example I have found online uses the following syntax

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>()
        .HasOptional(t => t.ParentObject)
        .WithMany(t => t.ChildObjects)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("parentId");
            m.MapRightKey("childId");
            m.ToTable("linkTable");
        });
}
```

But the MapLeftKey and MapRightKey actions are not recognised and give me the following error details...

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ForeignKeyAssociationMappingConfiguration'
>   does not contain a definition for 'MapLeftKey' and no extension method
>   'MapLeftKey' accepting a first argument of type
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ForeignKeyAssociationMappingConfiguration'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

According to [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.manytomanyassociationmappingconfiguration.mapleftkey(v=vs.113).aspx),the required assembly to be referenced is EntityFramework.dll

I have checked and I have a reference to the EntityFramework.dll which is the latest 6.1.3

Any suggestions as to what is wrong I'm pulling my hair out - the project is in VS 2012 and is an MVC project with Code-First From Database generated context etc.

**UPDATE**

removed - see update #3 below

**UPDATE #2**

After some more googling this is probably the closest that I can find to my basic issue.

[link to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457621/ef-code-first-on-existing-database-mapping-one-to-many)

I already have this table setup - I have a table (MyObject table) and a then a separate link-table that contains a parentId and childId - both of these columns refer to the Id field on the MyObject table.

Unfortunately, this db is legacy and I cannot change it and there is NO foreign key constraints for the above.

I have tried replicating the answer but I can't get it to work and some of the final code given has confused me - in particular the use of the parentId property that doesn't appear to exist in the initial class??

I can't believe it's this difficult to set up a many-to-many relationship that using 2 tables where the 2nd table is defining the relationships...I must be missing something vary simple???

**Update #3**

```
public partial class MyObject
{
    [Key]
    public int MyObjectId { get; set; }

    public string Desciption { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MyObject> ParentObject { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MyObject> ChildObjects { get; set; }
}
```

So my DB table looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyObject](
    [MyObjectId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Description] [varchar](60) NULL    
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyObjectRelations](
    [MyObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,    
    [MyObjectIdParentId] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

As you can see, both tables have used the same name for a column.

So if I had several records in the DB they would look like this...

MyObjectId

```css
table#t01 {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 th {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>MyObjectId</td>
    <td>Description</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Cars</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Bikes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Bentley</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>BMW</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Fast Car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Fast Bike</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Triumph</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>An Old Car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>An Old Bike</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>relationships</h3>
<table style="width:100%" id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>MyObjectId</td>
    <td>MyObjectParentId</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Include full line if code, please, what is the code before `.Map...`?

Comment: edited to show code - please note that there are a lot of other definitions that I have excluded as they are purely the auto-generated declarations and the issue is not with syntax from what I can tell as all the other EF references are recognised - it is only the MapLeftKey and MapRightKey that are presenting issues.

if it helps, VS prompts me to enter m.MapKey <<< this is recognised?

Comment: Can you add the codes for these two classes?

Comment: Based on your model class it's not a many-to-many relationship, it's one-to-many. Each object has many children and each object has one parent at most.

Comment: So, based on these tables the model in my answer is what you want, just renamed the column mappings to column names of the relation table.

Answer (score 1):

These methods are member of `ManyToManyAssociationMappingConfiguration` that uses for setting up many to many associations not for one-to-many associations that you have in your code.

assuming each `MyObject` has many `ParentObjects` and each `ParentObject` has many `ChildObjects` it should be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>()
    .HasMany(t => t.ParentObjects)
    .WithMany(t => t.ChildObjects)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("MyObjectId");
        m.MapRightKey("MyObjectParentId");
        m.ToTable("linkTable");
    });
```

where the class looks like

```
public partial class MyObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Desciption { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MyObject> ParentObjects { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MyObject> ChildObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: To clarify...this is a self-referencing table with a another table used to store the mappings...

Comment: Each object can have 0 or multiple children AND 0 or multiple parents... It's many to many.

Comment: if so, then the ` public virtual MyObject ParentObject { get; set; }` must be  public virtual List<MyObject> ParentObject { get; set; }

Comment: Ok...so this is getting much close - thank you Taher.

Comment: The initial issue was that I was defining ParentObjects and ChildObjects in my code as ICollection<MyObject> - the code I posted as an example is not my actual code as I do not want to publicly show production code for various reasons and so I wrote seudo code.  Now I have defined them as List<MyObject> I have the options of using MapLeftKey and MapRightKey.

My next problem is 2 fold...

Comment: 1. the relationships are 0..* - so if I use .HasMany() does this not mean 1..* ?

I have tried using .HasOptional but then the following .WithMany does not like being passed t.ChildObjects

2. When defining the mapping I'm getting a conflict because MyObject actually has a property called "parentId" and so this can't be defined against the model in the mapping.

Comment: 1. With many to many relationship, each object can have zero or more of the other object, so there is no problem. 2. if each child can have many parents, what is the `parentId` for?

Comment: OK...I think by trying to not divulge too much about my actual code I am confusing matters more...I shall try to simplify my explanation....I'll edit my original post